# Regarding write into file in csv

Tags: c++, csv

I have a CSV which must be read and have duplicate values removed before it gets written.

Duplicate value would be based on two columns (date, price) (AND conditional statement). Therefore in the example below row 1, row 2, and row 4 would get written to CSV. Row 3 would qualify as a duplicate (since the same date and price match row 1) and would be excluded (not written to CSV).

```
address      floor       date         price
40 B STREET    18        3/29/2015    2200000
40 B STREET    23        1/7/2015     999000
40 B STREET    18        3/29/2015    2200000
40 B STREET    18        4/29/2015    2200000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: Read into `std::ofstream`.

Comment: This is not a code writing service, you need to have some code and specific problem (for example, maybe how you might handle parsing quoted strings containing commas). Look to break your problem down, how to read the file into some data structure, how to process it ("duplicate values removed") and how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map of date and price for finding duplicates. I am not sharing the complete code, but this will provide you a pointer of how to do what you want.

1) Create a map of date and price.

```
std::map<std::string, long> dataMap;
```

2) Read a line from the CSV. Do a lookup in the dataMap. If `key` (date) is found, check `value` (price), if both match, then it is a duplicate and you should ignore this record.

```
// Read a line from CSV and parse it to store
// different values in below variables. This should
// be in a loop where each loop will be fetching
// a line from the CSV. The loop should continue till
// you reach end of the input CSV file.
int floorValue;  
std::string addressValue;  
std::string dateValue; 
long priceValue;

// The benefit of using map is observed here, where you  
// can find a particular date in O(log n) time complexity  
auto it = dataMap.find(dateValue)
if (it != dataMap.end())
    if (it->second == priceValue)
        // Ignore this record
else
{
    // Write this entry into another CSV file.  
    // You can later rename this to the original  
    // CSV file, which will give an impression that  
    // your duplicate entries have been removed  
    // from the original CSV file.  
}
```

Comment: As @Fire Lancer pointed out, "this is not a code writing service". You need to put in some effort. Write some code and if you face any issues there, post your progress or specific issues here.